# Convenient way to find out whether onReceive on BroadcastReceiver was called while the application was running?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a static registration for BroadcastReceiver for handling SMS in Manifest. Is there a proper way to find out whether onReceive() method on that receiver class was called while the application was running or not ?

This is required so, I can start a activity if SMS was received when application was not running, otherwise, just process information and display some notification.

Answer (score 0):

Track visibility of your application yourself by using `Activity.onPause()`, `Activity.onResume()` methods and a static boolean. Store "visibility" status in some other class. Good choices are your own implementation of the `Application` or a `Service` (there are also [a few variations][4] of this solution if you'd like to check activity visibility from the service).

***Example***
This example provides the skeleton code for one activity, but you can add more booleans if you need to track more than one Activity.

Implement custom `Application` class (note the `isActivityVisible()` static method):

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

      public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
      }  

      public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;
      }

      public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
      }

      private static boolean activityVisible;
    }
```

Register your application class in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application
        android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Add `onPause` and `onResume` to every `Activity` in the project (you may create a common ancestor for your Activities if you'd like to, but if your activity is already extended from `MapActivity`/`ListActivity` etc. you still need to write the following by hand):

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      MyApplication.activityResumed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      MyApplication.activityPaused();
    }
```